# ¿Ajax no regresa a la función success usando enctype = "multipart/form-data"?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Por medio de un formulario Modal y usando una función ajax guardo una entidad Material y un archivo del tipo jpeg.

Este es mi vista modal:

```
@model MaterialViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Nuevo material";
    Layout = null;
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/js/fileUpload.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/css/fileUpload.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/popup/popupstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="modal-header modal-header-success">

    <h3 class="modal-title" style="text-align: center;">
        xxxxx
        <button type="button" class="close panelTitleTxt glyphicon glyphicon-remove landing-icon" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
    </h3>
</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateForCategory", "CategoriasMateriales", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="modal-body">
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/toastr")

        <br />

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CategoriaId)
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoriaId, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-sm-3 popup-labelfont"})
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CategoriaId, Model.CategoriasMaterialViewModel, new {@class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoriaId, "", new {@class = "label label-danger"})
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Descripcion, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-sm-3 popup-labelfont"})
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Descripcion, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control", maxlength = "200"}})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Descripcion, "", new {@class = "label label-danger"})
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("Imagen", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-sm-3 popup-labelfont"})
                <div class="col-md-offset-0 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-8">
                    <!-- image-preview-filename input [CUT FROM HERE]-->
                    <div class="input-group image-preview">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control image-preview-filename" disabled="disabled"> <!-- don't give a name === doesn't send on POST/GET -->
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <!-- image-preview-clear button -->
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger image-preview-clear" style="display: none;">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Clear
                            </button>
                            <!-- image-preview-input -->
                            <div class="btn btn-info image-preview-input">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>
                                <span class="image-preview-input-title">Browse</span>
                                <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif" name="upload" /> <!-- rename it -->
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </div><!-- /input-group image-preview [TO HERE]-->
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input class="btn btn-success" id="btnSave" type="submit" value="Guardar"/>
                    <input aria-hidden="true" class="btn btn-md btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal" id="btncancel" type="button" value="Cancelar"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/toastr")
                @Html.Partial("_Toastr")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<script>    
    $('form').submit(function () {

        $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            window.LoadMateriales();
        });
    });

    $('.modal').modal({
        keyboard: true,
        show: false
    });
    // Jquery draggable
    $('.modal-dialog').draggable({
        handle: ".modal-header"
    });
</script>
```

Este es mi script ajax:

```
  $('form').submit(function () {
  var $form = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    url: this.action,
    type: this.method,
    contentType: this.enctype,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.success) {
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            //Refresh
            //location.reload();
            $('#replacetarget').load(result.url);
        } else {
            $('#myModalContent').html(result);
            //bindForm();
        }
    }
  });
});
```

La cual se comunica con este metodo de mi controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CreateForCategory(MaterialViewModel material, HttpPostedFileBase upload)
{    
    var materialDomain = Mapper.Map<MaterialViewModel, Material>(material);

    if (upload != null && upload.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var imagen = new Imagen
        {
            Nombre = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(upload.FileName),
            TipoContenido = upload.ContentType
        };

        using (var reader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(upload.InputStream))
        {
            imagen.Contenido = reader.ReadBytes(upload.ContentLength);
        }

        materialDomain.Imagen = imagen;
    }

    _materialRepository.Create(materialDomain);


    string url = Url.Action("MaterialesPorCategoriaIndex", "CategoriaMateriales");

    return Json(new { success = true, url = url }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

El tema es que *si no trato de cargar la imagen junto con la entidad el json retornado por el método llega a la función y puedo cerrar el modal o mostrar algún mensaje*, pero ***si trato de cargar la imagen*** junto con la entidad **el json ya no regresa a la función y este me genera un nuevo html solo con la cadena cargada al objeto json.**

¿Alguna idea de como solucionar este problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La manera correcta de enviar mediante el método jQuery.ajax un form multipart/form-data es utilizando la clase FormData:

```js
  $('form').submit(function () {
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    $.ajax({
      url: this.action,
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function (result) {
        if (result.success) {
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            //Refresh
            //location.reload();
            $('#replacetarget').load(result.url);
        } else {
            $('#myModalContent').html(result);
            //bindForm();
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Asegúrate de poner el contentType a false para evitar que jQuery le dé valor por ti. También debe poner el valor de processData a false para evitar que jQuery trate de procesar los datos del FormData.

Comment: Hola Asier: Muchas gracias me funciona de maravilla!!!

Answer (score 1):

No puedes usar `$.ajax` con multipart, debes usar librerías como ser

[jquery.fileDownload](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload)

[jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

con estas librerias puedes subir archivos y datos en un mismo post

Tienes ejemplo

[jQuery-File-Upload.MVC5](https://github.com/TheKalin/jQuery-File-Upload.MVC5)

que implementan estas librerías en `asp.net mvc`

Answer (score 1):

Cambie la forma en que obtienes los datos de la forma.

Puedes agregar la propiedad **error** para ver los detalles si es que estas teniendo una excepción:

```
 $('form').submit(function () {

  var data = new FormData(this); // <-- 'this' es tu forma

  $.ajax({
    url: this.action,
    type: this.method,
    contentType: this.enctype,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.success) {
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            //Refresh
            //location.reload();
            $('#replacetarget').load(result.url);
        } else {
            $('#myModalContent').html(result);
            //bindForm();
        }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        //Checar error aqui
        console.log(jqXHR + " - " + textStatus+ " - " +errorThrown);
    }
  });
});
```